# Disable recent query suggestions in Android's global Quick Search Box?

Tags: android, autosuggest, quick-search

I've implemented a ContentProvider to add custom suggestions to my applications Quick Search Box. It works great within my app. However I also included it into the global search and it works different there. Whenever I start a search in the global search and I select one of my suggestions, this suggestion is saved and presented the next time I open the global search. What I don't like is that my current suggestions are below the ones I clicked before.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

I am currently thinking of integrating recent suggestions in my ContentProvider to provide both - recent and custom suggestions. Though I am afraid this will result in having the same suggestions twice - first from the global search and then from my ContentProvider...

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it is possible by providing the [SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT) value in the [SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID) column.

As usual this is described in the Android developer documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#ManagingShortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to create a custom `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider` as described [here](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html).

From in there, simply return an empty cursor or null.

Comment: interesting idea, but how do I use both - a SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider and [custom suggestion](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html). As far as I understand it only one of the two can be used. It is referenced by the 'android:searchSuggestAuthority'

Comment: In the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider, you can return a cursor, right? So, try to use a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html - MergeCursor that contains both the search suggestions and your results.